# Entity Framework 6 Adding Child Object Several Layers Down

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, parent

So I have a DB-First Entity Framework, with these models:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Ward Ward { get; set; }
}
    public partial class Ward
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Ward()
    {
        this.FinancialAccounts = new HashSet<FinancialAccount>();
    }

    public int WardID { get; set; }
    public string WardLastName { get; set; }
    public string WardFirstName { get; set; }
    public string WardMiddleName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FinancialAccount> FinancialAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class FinancialAccount
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public FinancialAccount()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int FinancialAccountID { get; set; }
    public int WardID { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
    public virtual Ward Ward { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

    public partial class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int FinancialAccountID { get; set; }
    public int DepositOrWithdrawalID { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CheckNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual DepositOrWithdrawal DepositOrWithdrawal { get; set; }
    public virtual FinancialAccount FinancialAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it's set up to have a User, that has a one-to-one relationship with its child Ward, which has a one-to-many relationship with it child FinancialAccounts, which has a many-to-many relationship with its child Transactions.

I've gotten some conflicting advice on how to handle updating the Transactions to the proper FinancialAccount, which is to the correct Ward, which is to the correct User. The User will be grabbed by using Session["UserID"] like this:

```
        using (var db = new DBGAPEntities())
        {
            var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(Session["UserID"]));                
        }
```

Most of the advice I've gotten to this point is for adding child entities while also creating the parent entity, but what if I want to just add a new child record(Transaction) to the parent(FinancialAccount) which is tied to the correct Ward, and thus the correct User.

Is it better to rework my model so that every table is at most two relationships away, or is there a clean way to do this? I've attempted using:

```
        using (var db = new DBGAPEntities())
        {
            var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(Session["UserID"])).Include(b => b.Ward.Select(c => c.FinancialAccount));
        }
```

But I get the error "Ward does not contain a definition for Select." Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select User with his `Ward` object and include his `FinancialAccounts` you can do this like :

```
using (var db = new DBGAPEntities())
{
    var user = db.Users.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(Session["UserID"]))
        .Include(b => b.Ward)
        .Include(b => b.Ward.FinancialAccounts)
        .First();
}
```

To add new Transaction
you should know FinancialAccountID, DepositOrWithdrawalID , TypeID , TransactionDate , TransactionAmount

```
using (var db = new DBGAPEntities())
{
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    //populate  transaction model with values
    db.Transactions.Add(transaction);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then entity framework will set TransactionID after saving it

Comment: That's great for reading the data, which I appreciate the clarity on, but how do I then add a Transaction to the appropriate FinancialAccount?

Comment: Thank you, that does help, but how do I know it will update to the user that's currently logged in to the session?

Comment: if you used the right `FinancialAccountID` which has relation to Ward which is connected to User then it will

Comment: in Ward Model add property UserID ,it  will make it easy to query ward using userid from session

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this gives me a lot more to work with.